# meaning of "move": "I moved from ... while I was ..."

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the sentences which I can't understand completely:

> I moved from a careless indigence while I was a student to an intermittent prosperity.

And here is more context:

> To talk about money is always to talk about oneself. I was spared the injury of poverty; after a difficult youth my parents achieved a degree of affluence before sinking into debt. They began to count their pennies, and endured the bitterness of losing their social status. Death came to them when they were in a state of near destitution. So far as I was concerned, I moved from a careless indigence while I was a student to an intermittent prosperity.

What does the writer mean?
Is he implying that he was first "a careless indigent" and then become a "student to an intermittent prosperity"?

Comment: No, I believe the intended reading of the sentence is *I moved from [ a careless indigence while I was a student ] to [ an intermittent prosperity ].* What does *become a student to something* even mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writer means that he/she moved from the state of careless indigence to the state of intermittent prosperity. So he was first *a careless indigent* and then became *an intermittent prosperity*

The *while I was a student* part is a bit ambiguous though. It could either mean that he was a student only in the state of careless indigence or that he was a student in both states.